# Trouble with redeploying Timer jobs during development

Tags: development, custom-timer-job

i have a project containing 1 timer job and 1SPpersistedObject.

when i deploy the project for the first time it works fine and i debug the correct code.

i then made a change and now it is debugging the wrong code.

i have checked the Gac cleaned out every relevant dll. i made sure that the wsp has been removed before i redeploy the project.

is their any other place that i should remove references to the dll files because their is something stuck somewhere causing me to be unable to test the Timer Job with new code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you remember to restart the SharePoint Timer Service (in services)? It caches the DLL files